# JFrame.setIconImage() not working

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe, imageicon

```
public class RType extends JFrame {

private static ImageIcon ICON = new ImageIcon("craft.png");

public RType() {

    add(new Board());
    setIconImage(ICON.getImage());

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("R - Type");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RType();
}
}
```

This code still works fine and compiles after I attempt to set an icon image for the JFrame, but there is no difference. I still see the default java-icon. Can someone detect the problem? "craft.png" is 20x20 pixels. It is correctly placed within the ressource folder (no ClassLoader-exceptions and no other compile-time errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ImageIcon(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29) expects a file reference, if the icon is an embedded resource, you will need to supply a `URL`

Something like...

```
private static ImageIcon ICON = new ImageIcon(RType.class.getResource("/craft.png"));
```

Assuming that `craft.png` is in the default directory and not some sub directory

Comment: cannot find symbol: method getRessource(String) in class Class<CAP#1>

Comment: Right, ressource is a weird word and only spelled with 1 "s" :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Although I tried a number of approaches and was never able to get the icon correctly set in the ULHC of the JFrame, I was able to get a full-sized icon (194 × 177 pixels) to show in the Task Bar, which for this project, is enough.

This is what worked for me:

```
    String sImageFileName = "/lb/icons/favicon.png";
    URL urlImageFileName = getClass().getResource(sImageFileName);

    if (urlImageFileName == null)
        System.out.println( "urlImageFileName: " + urlImageFileName + " Not Found." );
    else {
        ImageIcon oImageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(sImageFileName));
        setIconImage(oImageIcon.getImage());
    }  // end else
```

/lb is the root of your pkg as it appears in the current jar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

--Deprecated--

IntelliJ IDEA sometimes does not recognizes paths from the `src` folder, it does from the `out` folder though, so I suggest to compile your progect and get the path from there.

Example:

```
String iconPath = "out/production/projectName/com/media/icon.png";
jframe.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(iconPath).getImage());
```

Hope this will still help someone.

Comment: no - file paths will break on deploy

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for the notice, I hadn't try to deploy yet, I'll try to fix it